# hello : "world" How come this is valid javascript?

Tags: javascript

I was messing around in console when I typed in `echo : "test"` and to my suprised the string "test" was returned to console.

How come this is valid syntax without a ? in a `(boolean) ? trueresult : falseresult`

Are there possible uses except a fancy way to mess in console?

Comment: Well, it's a [label](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/label).

Comment: o_O i completely forgot about these things... last time I used them was like 15 years ago. Dindn't know they still existed.

Comment: The good news is that JavaScript doesn't support `goto`, so it's less likely you will get [attacked by a velociraptor](http://xkcd.com/292/).

Comment: @Ja͢ck:- Very good point Jack!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `echo:` is creating the [label](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/label) and hence the output

> **Description**
>
> You can use a label to identify a loop, and then use the break or
>   continue statements to indicate whether a program should interrupt the
>   loop or continue its execution.
>
> Note that JavaScript has NO goto statement, you can only use labels
>   with break or continue.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/225370/your-answer-is-in-another-castle-when-is-an-answer-not-an-answer 
I'll accept it, but keep in mind the documentation you are linking to might move and invalidate your link.

Comment: @MichaelDibbets:- Although it seems not very much relevant in this context to add the details for label but yes the point made by Jack was worth mentioning!

Comment: Yes, but I might not be the only one wondering what a label is. A marginal explanation is better than no explanation. I've seen the netscape documentation going into the mozilla documentation into the mdn and shifting urls several times over the course of years. This way your answer will still be relevant in a few years ;-)

Comment: @MichaelDibbets:- Point taken! And tried to add the detail as well! :)

Answer (score 2):

In this case `echo:` is creating a label.

See:  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/label

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/225370/your-answer-is-in-another-castle-when-is-an-answer-not-an-answer